# How can I convert a list of strings into numerical values?

Tags: python, string-parsing

I want to find out how to convert a list of strings into a list of numbers.

I have a php form through which user enters values for x and y like this:

```
X: [1,3,4]
Y: [2,4,5]
```

These values are stored into database as varchars. From there, these are called by a python program which is supposed to use them as numerical (numpy) arrays. However, these are called as plain strings, which means that calculation can not be performed over them. Is there a way to convert them into numerical arrays before processing or is there something else which is wrong?

Comment: Parse the strings and split them to form the array. This is not difficult. [Try something](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) along with the [strip()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.strip#str.strip) and [split()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.split#str.split) function to turn this into *numeric* values.

```
x = '[1,3,4]'
new_x = [int(i) for i in x.strip('[]').split(',')]
new_x
[1, 3, 4]
```

Use this list of `int`s as you see fit, e.g., passing them on to numpy etc.

```
from numpy import array

a = array(new_x)
a
array([1, 3, 4])

a * 4
array([ 4, 12, 16])
```

Comment: Thanks guys. But the thing is that this resulting array can not be multiplied or added with any other array. What I want this thing to do is being able to multiply and add like normal numerical arrays. :/

Comment: I will. I will post my complete snippet and posting code over here today.. let's see if this can be resolved.

Comment: @khan my solution gives you numbers, so I am not quite sure what you are looking for. I'll take a look at your updated question.

Comment: Yeah..i am in my office and will update the question once I get to home.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> block = "[1,3,4]"
>>> block = block.strip("[]")
>>> a = numpy.fromstring(block, sep=",", dtype=int)
>>> a
array([1, 3, 4])
>>> a*2
array([2, 6, 8])
```

Comment: It is still returned as a string. My point is that it should be returned as a numerical array. For instance:

>>> a = numpy.array( [2,3,4] )

Now when we do a*2:

>>> a*2

>>> array( [4,6,8] )

This is ideal. I want this to happen with my string but so far not able to do so. :/

Comment: What? That is not a string at all. It's a numpy array. I've updated the answer to maybe make it more clear what's going on.

Comment: I am sorry..I meant to say that it is returned as an array of characters rather than an array of numerical entities which have the capability to add up or get multiplied with another array of numbers like matrices.

Comment: ?? No it's not. Did you look at the answer?

Comment: Let me get to home and post my entire code over here for you guys for better comprehension.

Comment: this is another way of doing it..good..both you and levon are correct. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast
import numpy as np

def parse_array(s):
    return np.array(ast.literal_eval(s))

s = '[1,2,3]'
data = parse_array(s)    # -> numpy.array([1,2,3])
```

Comment: This gives error: 

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'array'

Comment: Works fine for me - 32-bit Python 2.7.2, numpy 1.5.1, on 64-bit Windows 7 Pro

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the `eval()` and `compile()` built-in functions to achieve your aim:

```
>>> lst_str = '[1,2,3]'
>>> lst_obj = compile(lst_str, '<string>', 'eval')
>>> eval(lst_obj)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Keep in mind that using `eval()` in this manner is potentially unsafe, however, unless you can validate the input.

Comment: @PauloScardine, I would imagine that it must be, but until I read Hugh Bothwell's post above, I didn't even know it existed. Still, `ast` apparently wasn't added until 2.6, so the `eval()` method might have some use in old versions.